# What is the meaning of Self-signed checkbox in WebStart properties in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar-signing

In Netbeans (I have the 6.5 version), in the project properties under Application> Webstart there is a self-signed checkbox.

What is its meaning?
When I need to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably to do with web start security. If you look at [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html#security) you will see that web start applications run in a sandbox unless they are signed. You can choose to generate a self-signed certificate instead of a verified one such as one from Verisign or Thawte.

Self-signing is fine if you're testing but if you're deploying something to production for public use, I'd recommend getting a proper certificate.